For Ruby extension, how should I save a reference in C or Rust side?
I'm working on a client-side caching library that caches objects in a HashMap.
A simple example is below:
fn insert(key: RString, obj: AnyObject) -> AnyObject {
    let rust_struct = self.get_data_mut(&*STORE_WRAPPER);
    rust_struct
        .hash_map
        .insert(key.unwrap().to_string(), Arc::new(obj));

        NilClass::new().into()
}

pub extern "C" fn Init_ruby_example() {
    Class::new("ObjectStore", None).define(|klass| {
        klass.def("insert", insert);
    });
}

And we can use it by
store = ObjectStore.new
def insert(store)
  store.insert('key1', 'some-val')
  store.insert('key2', Bar.new)
end

and we should query it by
insert(store)
store.get('key1') # expect it equals 'some-val'
store.get('key1') # expect it equals the bar object

For this example, the 'some-val' and the bar object could be freed by GC as no objects reference them.
So what should I do to avoid those objects being freed?
I think I can pin the value objects to avoid them being moved during GC compacting.
But how should I keep a reference on the Ruby side to avoid them being freed? I didn't find suitable c functions. rb_gc_register_address and rb_gc_unregister_address seem good, but rb_gc_unregister_address needs to loop through all registered objects which is slow.

Please edit your question and post your ruby code that shows what variables you want to do this to. Presumeably, fiddle provides all the tools necessary to interface ruby to C/Rust. Normally, if the variable stays in scope in ruby, it won't be reclaimed. But, I don't know enough about ruby to know if it will move it to a different location during GC (i.e. storage compaction). Also, I guess you pass a ruby object descriptor to C, and it can use the fiddle API to manipulate it. We also need to see your C code to see why you need to pin the variable's data (vs. deref the object)

thanks for your reply and sorry for the unclear description. I have updated my question.

What makes you think "For this example, the 'some-val' and the bar object could be freed by GC."? Do you have a proof of concept or have you experienced a real world issue where GC has disposed of these objects?

there is POC project https://github.com/yfractal/rust_arc_demo/tree/gc-bug for this. And I will improve my answer to make it more clear.
